# Javascript Object's method is not working

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to fire an alert to see at least my empty javascript object's method is working, but when I run the application it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm missing so far.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jsObject= {};

        jsObject.start = function () {
            alert('Worked');
            this.init();
            this.attachCustomHandlersOnOutputConsole();
            this.attachClickHandlersOnButtons();
        };

        jsObject.init = function () {
            //Code
        };

        jsObject.attachCustomHandlersOnOutputConsole = function () {
            //Code
        };

        jsObject.attachClickHandlersOnButtons = function () {
            //Code
        };

    });
</script>
```

This is my very first question on stackoverflow, I hope all the information that I should provide is correct.

Comment: You're not calling any of your object's functions.

Comment: Thank's a lot Robby.

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5ecstuao/

Comment: Like @RobbyCornelissen wrote, you've created the object but you're not doing anything with is. Add `jsObject.start();` to call it.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time guys.